How can I display foreign key data in a datagrid?
I need to display by id the ingredients from a linked database table.
I am using Entity Framework Core with generated scaffolds for the database . The code below is simplified version of the entity classes I'm working with.
public partial class Recipe
{
    public Recipe()
    {
        InterchangeabilityIngredients = new HashSet<InterchangeabilityIngredients>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int IdBrand { get; set; }
    public int IdIngredient { get; set; }
    public double MassPart { get; set; }
    public double PercentWeight { get; set; }

    public virtual RubberBrand IdBrandNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual Ingredient IdIngredientNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<InterchangeabilityIngredients> InterchangeabilityIngredients { get; set; }
}

IngredientsBrandGrid.ItemsSource = db.Recipe.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.IdBrand == currentbrid).ToList();

My DataGrid simplistically looks like this:
<DataGrid x:Name="IngredientsBrandGrid" SelectionMode="Single" IsReadOnly="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,60" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="NameIngredient" Binding="{Binding IdIngredientNavigation.NameIngredient}" Width="200">
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="MassPart" Binding="{Binding MassPart}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="PercentWeight" Binding="{Binding PercentWeight}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

But for some reason the column appears empty

I also tried adding incude() to the query, but the result is the same
IngredientsBrandGrid.ItemsSource = db.Recipe.Include(x=>x.IdIngredientNavigation).AsQueryable().Where(x => x.IdBrand == currentbrid).ToList();

Probably, it should be specified that this datagrid is located in TabControl. Because the datagrid located just in the window is displayed correctly.

.Include(x=>x.IdIngredientNavigation) should have done the trick. Note that the .AsQueryable() is not needed when building an expression, and with Linq-to-Entity it should be avoided since it can give a false sense of security, and may be concealing the issue in your case.
The first thing to check is whether your mappings are correct. That looks like it may be a one-to-one relationship between Recipe and Ingredient. By default, EF expects to map one-to-one via the PK on both tables. If you want the Recipe to contain an IdIngredient FK to the IdIngredientNavigation nav property then you need to configure this in the DbContext:
modelBuilder.Entity<Recipe>()
   .HasOne(x => x.IdIngredientNavigation)
   .WithOne() // Assuming ingredient doesn't have a Recipe nav property
   .HasPrincipalKey<Recipe>(x => x.IdIngredient);

One-to-one relationships have 3 ways they could be configured, PK-to-PK (default) FK on Left-side (Recipe.IdIngredient), or FK on Right-side (Ingredient.IdRecipe) If you aren't using PK-to-PK then you have to tell it how to find the FK.
The next thing to check is "what is 'db'?" in your code? Is this the DbContext, or some kind of wrapper around the DbContext. If you have some form of wrapper like a Repository or Unit of Work pattern that wraps the DbContext/DbSet doing something like:
public class DB 
{
    private readonly AppDbContext _context;

    public DB(AppDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Recipe> Recipe => _context.Recipe.ToList();
}

Then this would be a big no-no. Remove any abstraction around the DbContext and make sure you are using the DbContext directly for a start. If db.Recipe is not referencing the DbContext.Recipe DbSet then appending an .AsQueryable() will not make deferred execution or eager loading with .Include() work. These need to be applied to the EF implementation of IQueryable<Recipe>, namely the DbSet<Recipe>.
If you confirm that db.Recipe is referencing the DbContext.DbSet<Recipe> then the next thing to check would be if at runtime we are going to the same database as you think it should be connecting to. Add the following line and a breakpoint:
IngredientsBrandGrid.ItemsSource = db.Recipe.Where(x => x.IdBrand == currentbrid).ToList();
var connectionString = db.Database.GetConnectionString();
Inspect the connection string and confirm whether it is going to the database instance you expect. A fairly common issue is that the .exe.config file that gets set up at runtime gets out of sync with the expected database and the old database it ends up using doesn't have the related data you expect.
Also make sure you are using a real, and preferably a Relational database like SQL Server Express or PostgreSQL and not the in-memory provider. AFAIK navigation properties and eager loading don't work with the in-memory provider.
Hopefully that helps resolve the issue. I highly recommend using a ViewModel class for binding results like data grids rather than entities. Even with eager loading you are loading every column from the Recipe and ingredient when you only need the values displayed. If you create a simple POCO view model class called RecipeSummary with just the columns you need you can optimize the query down to:
IngredientsBrandGrid.ItemsSource = db.Recipe
    .Where(x => x.IdBrand == currentbrid)
    .Select(x => new RecipeSummary
    {
        RecipeId = x.Id,
        MassPart = x.MassPart,
        PercentWeight = x.PercentWeight,
        IngredientName = x.IdIngredientNavigation.Name
    }).ToList();

This will build an SQL statement optimized to the columns needed, not everything.
